# The LR/SC instructions and Release Consistency

Tags: riscv

The paper that introduced Release Consistency ("Memory Consistency and Event Ordering in Scalable Shared-Memory Multiprocessors" by K. Gharachorloo et al.) mentions a class of memory operations called "non-synchronization" (nsync), which are intended for competing, but not synchronizing, accesses to the data of other threads in chaotic relaxation algorithms.

Am I mistaken in thinking that LR and SC instructions in RISC-V, with the AQ and RL bits cleared, are nsync-class instructions? I ask because the RISC-V manual (Version 20190608-Base-Ratified, p. 50) states that with the AQ and RL bits cleared, LR and SC are: "...appropriate when the LR/SC sequence is used to implement a parallel reduction operation."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe so.   The preceding sentence ( in my -draft copy ) states:

> If neither bit is set on both LR and SC, the LR/SC sequence can be
>   observed to occur before orafter surrounding memory operations from
>   the same RISC-V hart.  This can be appropriate ....

What I think they are getting at is the lr/sc will only synchronize with the linked address (ok, cache line), so other memory locations between the lr/sc can remain in a looser order than this one.  Stated another way, the lr/sc doesn't have to wait for preceding items in the store buffer to make their way out to RAM unless there is some other fence-like operation pending.

As such, it would be inappropriate for implementing a mutex (as most multi-threaded programs consider the mutex a memory ordering point), but well suited for a counter or stack index.